# Having django select the right option for a html select tag

Tags: django

I have a template in django that is a pretty simple table that loads up based on the list passed into it from the view. a snippet of the HTML code:

```
{% for hou in bookings_list %}
    <tr value={{hou.pk}}>
       <td><a href="mailto:{{hou.user.user.email}}"> {{ hou.user.user.first_name }} {{ hou.user.user.last_name }}</a></td>
       <td> <select id="room_number" name={{hou.pk}} class="select form-control">
        <option value=-1 id=-1> ------ </option>
        {% for room in room_list %}
          <option value={{room.id}} id={{hou.pk}}>{{ room.room_name }}</option>              
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </td>

     <td> .. more stuff ..</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

(bookings_list is a list of bookings for housing that the user has booked (includes room they are assigned to unless no one assigned them a room from a new booking so it is NULL), the room list is a list of all possible rooms for the person in charge to select to assign to a user via the booking)

I have ajax working with a jquery change call that when the select is selected it gives the room_id to what ever room.id was selected on the front end and saves the record in the view.  But if I reload this page, the ------ always shows up.   I know I have to figure out how to set the selected for the option if the room_id from the hou is not null, just not sure how to go about that in this instance.

Comment: Do you want to remove the `------` if there is room in `room_list` or just putting `selected` in the option the user selects?

Comment: So the room list is a list of all rooms.  So I want the ----- to denote when a room hasn't been selected for a booking yet (users say they want a booking then someone a manager selects which room to put them in).  So when a new booking comes in, the room_id of the booking model is null.  Then when a manager selects a room from a room filled out in the select (via a room list based on just a simple table of room names and ids) then the room_id of the booking is set to what the manager selects. If the booking is loaded again with non null room_id, should show up as selected room in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `room` is a foreign key to `bookings`:

```
<td> <select id="room_number" name={{hou.pk}} class="select form-control">
        <option value=-1 id=-1> ------ </option>
        {% for room in room_list %}
          {% if hou.room.id == room.id %}
          <option value={{room.id}} id={{hou.pk}} selected>{{ room.room_name }}</option>  
          {% else %}
          <option value={{room.id}} id={{hou.pk}}>{{ room.room_name }}</option>  
          {% endif %}            
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </td>
```

Comment: Well I made that way more complicated in my head, haha thanks that did it like a charm!